# element side by side in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following

```
 <section class="page-element col-md-9 col-lg-7">
             <div class="page-element">part1</div>
        </section>
```

I want to add another section to be on the same line as part1

I tried this but what it does is put the row of `part2`, below `part1` and not side by side

```
<div class="row">
        <section class="page-element col-md-9 col-lg-7">
             <div class="page-element">part1</div>
        </section>

        <section class="page-element col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="page-element">part2</div>
        </section>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the page-element class do?

Comment: Come on, it's obviously Bootstrap, 12 cols per row grid system.

Comment: I googled `page-element` bootstrap, there were no helpful results.

Comment: There are only 12 columns in bootstrap, so you already used by 9 for the first section when in medium viewport width, and 7 when in larger viewport widths. Bootstrap clearly says that when the number of columns exceed 12, the next element will simply be wrapped to the next line/row. If you want to float them side by side, ensure that the `col-{size}-n` classes add up to 12 (or less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid system of Bootstrap contains **12 columns**, meaning that when your layout exceeds 12 columns (`col-md-9` and `col-md-12` adds up to 21 columns, for example), then wrapping will occur

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.
>
> [Source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)

A visual example is as follow:

```
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
| 1| | 2| | 3| | 4| | 5| | 6| | 7| | 8| | 9| |10| |11| |12|
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+

+------------------------------------------+ 
| col-md-9                                 | 
+------------------------------------------+ 

+---------------------------------------------------------+
| col-md-12                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

You will have to ensure that the column span of the elements to add up to 12, or less, in order for them to appear side by side (i.e. prevent wrapping):

```
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
| 1| | 2| | 3| | 4| | 5| | 6| | 7| | 8| | 9| |10| |11| |12|
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ +--+

+------------------------------------------+ +------------+
| col-md-9                                 | | col-md-3   |
+------------------------------------------+ +------------+
```

In the example below I have adjusted the column span of your second section so that they sum nicely to 12, with respect to the same column class of its previous sibling. I have added `col-xs-{n}` and `col-sm-{n}` classes so that the layout will still work on the narrow viewport sizes of embedded code snippets.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <section class="page-element col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-7">
    <div class="page-element">part1</div>
  </section>

  <section class="page-element col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-5">
    <div class="page-element">part2</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to do it.

```css
#row {
    overflow: hidden; /*allows div to have children that float*/
}
#first {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid red;   /*allows you to see the div*/
}
#second {
    border: 1px solid green; /*allows you to see the div*/
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
    <div id="first">part1</div>
    <div id="second">part2</div>
</div>
```